# What is the standard / recommended / as secure as possible practice for storing a user's OAuth token on Android?

Tags: java, android, security, sharedpreferences, keychain

iOS apps can store sensitive information in the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html). The Keychain is the standard place to persist something like a user's OAuth token.

Where should sensitive data (e.g. an OAuth token) be stored on an Android device?

There are many questions / articles out there on this subject but they all seem to recommend something different. Or present many options and explain that none are "secure". Given that none are truly "secure", what is the **standard** practice for storing sensitive information in the context of an Android application?

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate on Android's [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to store this.

There are a few good tutorials about how to use it, but for me [Udinic](https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)'s was the most interesting.